# Issue with Button Position Change in Python using Flet. Help-me

Tags: python, flutter, flet

I'm working on a Python project using the Flet library and I'm facing some challenges. Recently, I started implementing a 'No' button that, whenever the mouse hovers over it, should change its position. The goal is to make it impossible to click, forcing the use of the 'Yes' button. However, I'm having difficulty making the 'No' button change its location.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
import random
import flet as ft

def main(janela: ft.Page):
    janela.title = "Teste!"

    janela.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.DARK

    janela.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    janela.horizontal_alignment= ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    def fechar():
        janela.window_destroy()

    popup = ft.AlertDialog(
        #open=False,
        modal=True,
        title=ft.Text("Close!"),
        content="kkk", 
        actions=[ft.ElevatedButton("OK", on_click=fechar)],
        actions_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END
    )

    def yes():
        janela.dialog = popup
        popup.open = True
        janela.update()

    def MotionMouse(event):
        botao_No.top = random.randint(0, 500)
        botao_No.left = random.randint(0, 500)
        
        janela.update()

    pergunta = ft.Text("Do you want to close the window?!", scale=3)

    # pergunta.animate_position = random.randint(0, 500)
    #pergunta.animate_position.left = random.randint(0, 500)

    botao_Yes = ft.ElevatedButton("Yes", on_click=yes)
    botao_No = ft.ElevatedButton("No", top=50 , on_click=MotionMouse, on_focus=MotionMouse)
    janela.update()

    janela.add(pergunta)
    janela.add(botao_Yes)
    janela.add(botao_No)

    janela.window_prevent_close=False
    
    janela.update()

ft.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")
```

Can someone guide me on how to make the 'No' button change its position when the mouse hovers over it? Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I made some modifications to your code:

- added `on_hover`(event triggered when the button is hovered) -> `botao_No = ft.ElevatedButton("No", top=50, on_click=MotionMouse, on_hover=MotionMouse)`
- Moved the "No" button to a Stack -> `janela.add(ft.Stack([botao_No]))`

Complete code below:

```py
import random
import flet as ft


def main(janela: ft.Page):
    janela.title = "Teste!"

    janela.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.DARK

    janela.vertical_alignment = ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER
    janela.horizontal_alignment = ft.CrossAxisAlignment.CENTER

    def fechar():
        janela.window_destroy()

    popup = ft.AlertDialog(
        # open=False,
        modal=True,
        title=ft.Text("Close!"),
        content="kkk",
        actions=[ft.ElevatedButton("OK", on_click=fechar)],
        actions_alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.END
    )

    def yes():
        janela.dialog = popup
        popup.open = True
        janela.update()

    def MotionMouse(event):
        botao_No.top = random.randint(0, 500)
        botao_No.left = random.randint(0, 500)

        janela.update()

    pergunta = ft.Text("Do you want to close the window?!", scale=3)

    # pergunta.animate_position = random.randint(0, 500)
    # pergunta.animate_position.left = random.randint(0, 500)

    botao_Yes = ft.ElevatedButton("Yes", on_click=yes)
    botao_No = ft.ElevatedButton("No", top=50, on_click=MotionMouse, on_hover=MotionMouse)
    janela.update()

    janela.add(pergunta)
    janela.add(botao_Yes)
    janela.add(ft.Stack([botao_No]))

    janela.window_prevent_close = False

    janela.update()


ft.app(target=main, assets_dir="assets")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I solved the problem here, but now the popup is not opening. This error appears: 
self.__content._set_attr_internal("n", "content")
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_set_attr_internal'

Comment: It's because of `content="kkk"` in your `AlertDialog`. See example in docs [here](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/alertdialog#basic-and-modal-dialogs).